# How to ensure that USB Type A to COM device assignments stay the same after reboot in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, udev

I have two USB Type A to COM cables. Let’s call them: Cable 1 and cable 2.
Now I need to make sure their TTY device assignments stay the same after reboot. I am using Ubuntu.

For example I want to the computer to assign cable 1 to ttyUSB1 and cable 2  to ttyUSB2. Because of after the computer reboots, it will shuffle those cable to TTY assignments.

So I read some solutions for similar problems for other similar devices.

- [Fixed tty device assignments in Linux using udev](https://www.silabs.com/community/interface/knowledge-base.entry.html/2016/06/06/fixed_tty_deviceass-XzTf)
- [Assigning same USBtty linux to a device every time](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=90265)

But there is a problem.

So when I try this:

```
sudo udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 > usb0
sudo udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/ttyUSB1 > usb1
```

And this:

```
vimdiff usb0 usb1
```

The cables don’t have `ID_SERIAL_SHORT` value. There is no difference except names `ttyUSB0` and `ttyUSB1`. The cables are manufactured by the same company. So there is no difference by serial name.

Output of `diff first secnd`

```
1a2
> Bus 002 Device 020: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

Comment: Connect first cable, do `lsusb | tee first` in a shell, disconnect the cable connect the other, do `lsusb | tee secnd`, then `diff first secnd` and add the diff output text to your posting - with <pre> before and </pre> after it.

Comment: @Hannu I add the output to my post

Comment: If there's no difference, how do you expect the OS to tell the difference... That said, if both devices are connected at the same time, surely at least the port number (ID_PATH) should be different?

Comment: @grawity but will the ID_PATHs  be the same after rebooting ???

Comment: They are supposed to represent the physical connection, so hopefully yes...

Comment: I expected the above to show two more lines. Connect both devices, then do `lsusb | both` -- now diff the other two files (one at a time) against `both`.

Comment: @grawity OK. tommorow I will try to see are the ID_PATHs change.

Comment: @Hannu sorry I'm now not at work. So I will do that tomorrow.

Comment: @grawity You can write your comment as answer, thank you.

Comment: Ooops, that should be `lsusb | tee both` - a typo.

Comment: @Hannu Thanks man for taking care about this question, but I solve this problem using method that suggest gravity.

Comment: For the benefit of everyone else, and maybe enhancing your own understanding; why not add an answer telling what you did step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the answer let's understand the question first.
I have two devices. They are connected to computer by 'RS232 to USB' deices. And I have to config files. In each file there is a section called [SERIAL].

E.g.

```
[SERIAL]
port = /dev/ttyUSB1
```

After the reboot there is a chance that "dev path" can be changed.

Now I fix this problem by fixing `ID_PATH` by adding this code to 
`ACTION=="add",ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb",ENV{ID_PATH}=YOUR_ID_PATH, SYMLINK+="ttyUSBPort1"`

And as I understood we create link that refer to one of the `/dev/ttyUSB*`

So now after reboot there is a chance that `/dev/ttyUSBPort1` will refer to another `/dev/ttyUSB*` but it does not prevent me as in my config file the port is set as `/dev/ttyUSBPort1` and this port does not change.